# URL re write internal server error

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite a url on my categories page.

https://www.samedicalspecialists.co.za/category?category=breast-surgeon

I want to make it :

https://www.samedicalspecialists.co.za/category/breast-surgeon

I have this on my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)$ /category?category=$1 [L]
```

When I click the category I get internal server error, please help

Update
The full htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# if a file without .php extension is requested, rewrite it to .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1.php [L]
# rewrite everything else (except /listing) to /listing?url=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !listing
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /listing?url=$1 [L]

#categories
Options -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)$ /category?category=$1 [L]
```

The other rules are working its just the catgories

Comment: it's when you click on the link or when you add it to your htaccess. If it's when you click it's not a rule problem but a code problem with your PHP script

Comment: It's when I added the htaccess then click on the link, the other pages are working fine and the page category.php is have just var_dump @Inazo

Comment: dou you have add the mod_rewrite module to you apache ?

Comment: @Inazo I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#categories
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)$ /category?category=$1 [NC,L]

# if a file without .php extension is requested, rewrite it to .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1.php [L]

# rewrite everything else (except /listing) to /listing?url=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !listing
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /listing?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I'm facing another problem when I add the states, the